# Asp.Net Membership Password Resets without symbols

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership, sqlmembershipprovider

I'm using the asp.net Membership Provider in an application.
I'm also using the "out of the box" asp:PasswordRecovery control.

My client is complaining that the new passwords being issued are too complicated. 
**e.g. }>;-(hYrS^OTfY**

Are there any small tweaks I can make so the new passwords only contain letters and numbers?

thanks!

Comment: I looked and I couldn't find a way to affect the functionality of ResetPassword() through the web.config. Chances are you'd have to create your own solution to the problem.

Comment: This article has more information on how to create a custom solution: http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/837990

Comment: Thanks Greg!
I will post the code I develop from that article later this week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Text;

namespace TS.Common.MembershipProvider
{
    public class MembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
    {
        /// Create an array of characters to user for password reset.
        /// Exclude confusing or ambiguous characters such as 1 0 l o i
        string[] characters = new string[] { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
            "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "m", "n",
            "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

        const int DefaultResetPasswordLength = 10;
        private int ResetPasswordLength;

        // Create a more user friendly password to avoid confusion when
        // trying to key in the new value
        public override string GeneratePassword()
        {
            string newPassword = string.Empty;
            System.Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < ResetPasswordLength; i++)
            {
                newPassword +=
                characters[rnd.Next(characters.GetUpperBound(0))];
            }
            return newPassword;
        }
    }
```

}